# something "to utilize" or "for utilizing" or "for utilization"?

Tags: prepositions

I want to choose a title for my article. In this article I have investigated the characteristics of some special buildings in modern countries and I want to utilize them for developing countries.
Which one of the following is correct?

1. An investigation of the characteristics of the buildings "to
   utilize" in developing countries;
2. An investigation of the characteristics of the buildings "for utilizing" in developing countries;
3. An investigation of the characteristics of the buildings "for utilization" in developing countries

Comment: Based purely on the choices you listed, *for utilization* would be best but *for use* would be far better.

Meanwhile, *the buildings* will never need the article *the* in that context; it should always be just *buildings*.

Then, d’you not fear falling foul of the post-colonial lobby in half of British Academia? To such people *An investigation of the characteristics of  buildings for use in developing countries* is clearly to suggest that only *developed* countries have buildings and many reasonable readers might agree.

Also, why not drop *An investigation of (the)*?

Comment: A survey of buildings' features for use in developing countries.

Answer (score -1):

All three are acceptable, although I wonder if

> An investigation of the characteristics of buildings constructed in the country

or

> An investigation of the required characteristics of buildings in the country

might be clearer and more direct ways of asking what I think you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't mean the phrases that you mentioned. I wanna choose a title for my article. I have investigated the characteristics of some special buildings in modern countries and I want to utilize them for developing countries.

Comment: If your focus is on regulated requirements for buildings, you might phrase it "An investigation of building codes...".

Answer (score -1):

I believe that all are fine, but 3 is the best. For option 1, it would be better if you put it in the passive voice, i.e. "to be utilized". Hope it helps!